# The bucket size in TC-HTB

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-traffic, traffic-shaping, iproute2

I study the behavior of tc-HTB.

I did a tc setting like the below.

After reading [**The bucket in tbf**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100785/bucket-size-in-tbf), I expect its burst size will be rate / HZ.

```
sudo /sbin/tc qdisc del dev s1-eth1 root
sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev s1-eth1 root handle 1:0 htb
sudo /sbin/tc class add dev s1-eth1 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 200mbit
sudo /sbin/tc filter add dev s1-eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 \
match ip tos 0x0 0x0 flowid 1:1
```

But it wasn't. It shows the below result. The burst value is 1600. I think it is so small compared its rate 200Mbps.

```
sudo tc -s -s -d -r c ls dev s1-eth1

class htb 1:1 root prio 0 quantum 200000 rate 200000Kbit ceil 200000Kbit 
linklayer ethernet burst 1600b/1 mpu 0b overhead 0b cburst 1600b/1 mpu 0b 
overhead 0b level 0 buffer [000003e8] cbuffer [000003e8] 

 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
 lended: 0 borrowed: 0 giants: 0
 tokens: 1000 ctokens: 1000
```

I also find `tc-htb` source code. `iproute2/tc/q_htb.c` also says

```
//Buffer value is given from burst argument.

    if (!buffer)
        buffer = rate64 / get_hz() + mtu;
    if (!cbuffer)
        cbuffer = ceil64 / get_hz() + mtu;
```

Despite of its source code,

Why is the burst value small compared to its rate?

Surely, I can add a option `burst` option as needed.

But I want to know the reason the burst value is so small automatically.

Could you give me a little hint?

Thanks!